# Xcode UI Failure (bot failure only): "Timed out waiting for key event to complete"

Tags: xcode7, xcode-ui-testing, xcode-bots

I have been encountering this error around textFields for a while now, and I'm trying to make sense of what this error means.

[image: Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - failed: Timed out waiting for key event to complete]

This failure happens sometimes when typing into a text field that contains an "x" button that will clear text. If you start typing into a clear field with no button, the "x" button will appear, and then clicking the "x" causes the field to become blank again and that button disappears as well.

Note that this is a failure that only happens to bots, testing locally works just fine every time.

Typing into fields that don't have a "x" button will always work, this failure is only happening in this specific case. I have already disconnected the hardware keyboard, since the app has no problem typing into other types of text fields without a clear button.

Clicking on the "x" button always passes, but subsequently typing into the cleared field results in the above "Timed out waiting for key event to complete" failure.

Is anyone else experiencing this failure? Is the button appearing in the text field causing Xcode bots to get confused with the page hierarchy? Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: i've been experiencing this issue as well

Comment: have you tried to return focus on the textField (by tapping)?